# Bamboo intermittently fails with "not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" in Source Code Checkout task

Tags: git, bamboo

My Bamboo task for "Source Code Checkout" is failing intermittently with a variety of git-related errors including:

- `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`
- `Can't create local repository folder E:\bamboo-build-dir\_git-repositories-cache\<GUID>`

The exceptions indicates the working directory is `\git-repositories-cache\<GUID>`

Answer (score 4):

This can happen under the following circumstances:

1. "Enable repository caching on remote agents" under the repository setting is true
2. Multiple "Source Code Checkout" tasks run simultaneously in parallel

In this case, it appears there is a bug in Bamboo in that it does not correctly handle simultaneous updates to the git repositories cache.  When multiple threads attempt to execute git commands on the cache simultaneously, these intermittent errors occur.

A workaround for this bug is to untick "Enable repository caching on remote agents".

For background on this feature see: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/how-stored-git-caches-speed-up-builds-690848923.html